# How to map a dataset with a function which contains a Tensorflow session?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-hub

I have a dataset in the form of a Tensorflow `DatasetV1Adapter` object.

```
<DatasetV1Adapter shapes: OrderedDict([(labels, (6,)), (snippets, ())]), types: OrderedDict([(labels, tf.int32), (snippets, tf.string)])>

# Example Output
OrderedDict([('labels', <tf.Tensor: id=37, shape=(6,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)>), ('snippets', <tf.Tensor: id=38, shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'explanationwhy the edits made under my username hardcore metallica fan were reverted they werent vandalisms just closure on some gas after i voted at new york dolls fac and please dont remove the template from the talk page since im retired now892053827'>)])

OrderedDict([('labels', <tf.Tensor: id=41, shape=(6,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)>), ('snippets', <tf.Tensor: id=42, shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'daww he matches this background colour im seemingly stuck with thanks  talk 2151 january 11 2016 utc'>)])
```

As you can see, it contains an `OrderedDict` object with keys of `labels` and `snippets`. The latter is basically what matters because it contains strings of text that I wished to convert to vectors using sentence embedding.

To do this, I decided to use the [Universal Sentence Encoder](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2) (USE) from tensorflow hub. It basically accepts a list of sentences as the input and will output a vector with a length of 512 as its output. One thing to note is that tensorflow hub cannot be executed during if eager execution is enabled. Therefore, we have to define a session to be able to use USE with tensorflow hub.

However, I wish to use [`map`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) provided by tensorflow. But the question rise as **how am I supposed to define a function that has a tensorflow session within it? And to use that function and map it on the dataset, do I need to define another tensorflow session?**

My first approach was to actually do that. Specifically, by defining a function that contains a tensorflow session. Then, start a new tensorflow session and tries to map the function to that dataset in that session.

Note that I defined the USE sentence embedding model outside of the session.

```
# Sentence embedding model (USE)
embed = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2")

def to_vec(w):
    x = w['snippets']
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        vector = sess.run(embed(x))
    return vector

with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
        # try_data is the DatasetV1Adapter object
        sess.run(try_data.map(to_vec))
```

But I got this error in the end

```
RuntimeError: Module must be applied in the graph it was instantiated for.
```

Alternatively, I tried to define the function inside the tensorflow session, like so

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])

    def to_vec(w):
        x = w['snippets']
        vector = sess.run(embed(x))
        return vector
    sess.run(try_data.map(to_vec))
```

But that didn't worked and I still got the same error. After doing some searching, I stumbled upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52392407/tensorflow-module-must-be-applied-in-the-graph-it-was-instantiated-for) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44418442/building-tensorflow-graphs-inside-of-functions), that said I have to define a `tf.Graph` and pass it in the session.

```
graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
        sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
        def to_vec(w):
            x = w['snippets']
            vector = sess.run(embed(x))
            return vector

        sess.run(try_data.map(to_vec))
```

Yet, I still received the same error. I also tried to define the USE inside the session and it still results in the same error.

From there, I was quite confused about how to do this. Does anybody have any idea on something that I missed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you don't. Tensorflow will call the function you pass to `Dataset.map` in graph mode (it only calls the function once and uses the resulting graph for each example, so you probably don't have to worry about possibly running preparation stuff associated with hub (downloading etc) for every example).

I'm not overly familiar with tensorflow hub, but try the following.

```py
def map_fn(inputs):
    snippets = inputs['snippets']
    # you -may- be able to pull the line below outside of map_fn
    # it probably won't affect performance
    embed = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2")
    vector = embed(snippets)
    return vector


dataset = dataset.map(map_fn)
```

Comment: Wow that actually solves the error I was asking about. Until I found another error saying that TF-hub inside of a function is not currently supported. But anyways, thank you so much!

Comment: try moving the `embed = ` line outside the function.

Comment: If I do that, then how am I suppose to map it to the dataset?

Comment: I imagine `vector = embed(snippets)` will construct the graph. Again, not certain how `hub` works, but that would be 'tensorflow-onic'.